# forward slashes replaced with backward slashes

Tags: java, string, batch-file, ant, groovy

I am learning groovy and executing ant through groovy. While testing I am struck at a point and don't know how to continue or resolve the issue

Here goes the issue:
I am trying to execute a batch command through ant inside groovy so my code goes like this

```
ant.exec(executable: task, failonerror: true)
```

my task is to delete a directory which is like this

```
def task = "rmdir /Q /S <path to folder>"
```

but when I execute this program i get this error

```
Caught: : Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "rmdir \Q \S <path to folder>": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "rmdir \Q \S <path to folder>": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTask.java:672)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.execute(ExecTask.java:495)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at Test.cleanup(Test.groovy:20)
    at Test$cleanup.call(Unknown Source)
    at Test.main(Test.groovy:13)
```

I dont know how but the forward slashes `"/"` are converted to back slashes `"\"`

so the command which should be  `"rmdir /Q /S <path to folder>"` becomes `"rmdir \Q \S <path to folder>"` and the error is thrown as the command is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably the ant thinks, that there is a path involved, that needs fixing.  The executable usually only point to the binary and then you add the args.

```
ant.exec(executable: 'rmdir', failonerror: true) {
    arg(value: '/Q')
    arg(value: '/S')
    arg(value: '<path to folder>')
}
```

And BTW: there is also `ant.delete(dir:'<path to folder>')`

Comment: hey that worked but have a doubt it showed the console output as 
 [exec] rmdir: `/Q': No such file or directory
     [exec] rmdir: `/S': No such file or directory
     [exec] rmdir: `<path to folder>': No such file or directory
<br> the options are parsed as separate file directories

Comment: thanks, ant.exec(executable: 'rmdir', failonerror: true) {
    arg(value: '/Q /S <path to folder>')
}
worked for me